# How to create trigger for broken cars using IF statement

Tags: mysql

I want to create a trigger that will not allow to rent a car if it is currently being repaired. Im quite new in triggers... could anyone shed some light on this aspect of triggers? My assumptions would be that it would something like...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `inspections_const` BEFORE UPDATE ON `inspections` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    SET NEW.booking_id = IF.repair_complete = 'No' 
                          THEN 'Allow booking'
                          ELSE 'Do not allow'  
                     END;                   
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Table is

```
CREATE TABLE `inspections` (
  `inspection_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `inspection_date` date NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `problem` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `repair_complete` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL,
  `mechanic_id` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `booking_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `booking_date` date NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `invoice_no` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `chauffeur_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vehicle_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `chauffeur_req` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL,
  `special_instructions` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `TheDuration` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: i assume there is somekind of `rent` table representing rented vehicles based on your query and seeing `NEW.booking_id` i assume that table is called `booking` ? If so on that table you would make a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and use SIGNAL/ Or simulate that with UPDATE  to stop the insert when the `inspections` has that `vehicle_id` and the `repair_complete` is `NO`

Comment: What do you mean inspections_const 
@EDIT: I added a bookings table

Comment: i meant table `inspections` i've copy / pasted the wrong part.

Comment: Well thanks for sheding some light. !

Comment: i've posted some trigger code which might do the trick you looking for it might have a missing condition or something like that.. But it should help you on the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tested it so it might have a missing condition or something like that. But it should help you on the correct path

**Query**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `check_repair` BEFORE INSERT ON `bookings` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    # We need to save the "count"
    DECLARE inspections_count INT DEFAULT 0;

    # Check if where is a repair going which matches the vehicle_id
    SELECT
      1 INTO inspections_count # store the "count" into the variable.
    FROM inspections
    WHERE
        inspections.vehicle_id = NEW.vehicle_id
      AND
        repair_complete = 'No'
    ORDER BY 
     inspections.start_date DESC
   LIMIT 1;

    # if there is a "count" stop the insert.
    IF inspections_count = 0 THEN 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'vehicle is in repair';
    END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What does the COUNT(*) bit do?
Why do you DECLARE inspections_counts

Comment: *"What does the COUNT(*) bit do?"* @PawełSzuszkiewicz i reviewed the query the `COUNT()` ideally should't even be used there in the first place  and editted the answer with a more "optimized" version which uses `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` because iám using `ORDER BY 
     inspections.start_date DESC
   LIMIT 1` .. Make sure to reload the page to see all edit changes.

Comment: I keep getting an error...
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF inspections_count = 0 THEN 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT =' at line 20

Ive checked it out doesnt seem to be wrong anywhere

Comment: @PawełSzuszkiewicz there needs to be a `;` after `LIMIT 1`